# Handling UITableView selection stack

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView representing articles of user's most likely interested topic based on their selection.

The stack looks like this:

```
home
+----------+
| topic A  |
| topic B  |           C related topics
| topic C  |---------> +----------+
+----------+ selected  | topic C  |           C-1 related topics
                       | topic C-1|---------> +----------+
                       | topic C-2| selected  |topic C-1 |
                       +----------+           |topic C-1-1
                                              |topic C-1-2 
                                              +----------+
```

This can go on and on, and I want to let users trace their selection,
which means they can go back to the previous table but not directly to the home table.

How can I hold the whole stack for user without messing up the app memory mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so, by maintaining a plist file containing your tree version of table content. Then after on selection of items you just need to grab the data for the key and show the key content in tableview. This will continue until user find the root element.

To make good user experience you can customize the back button and can load the content from plist file for appropriate key.

For example if users current position is n then on back button press you can load content for key n-1 and so on..

Hope this will help you.